# Sum two rows with different IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
ID | Field A | Quantity
1  |  A   | 10 
2  |  B   | 20
3  |  C   | 30
```

I would like to sum the fields with ids `1` and `3` in a way that result will be:

```
ID | Field A | Quantity
1  |  A   | 40 
2  |  B   | 20
```

Sounds to me more like code manipulation rather than SQL, but still want to try it.

My DMBS is sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what method to use to combine 1,3 `ID` but you could try case:

```
select 
case when id in (1,3) then 1 else id end
, min("Field A") "Field A"
, sum(quantity) quantity from myTable 
group by case when id in (1,3) then 1 else id end
```

The above uses `group by` to aggregate the data.  In this case it organizes the `ID` field using some logic to combine 1,3.  All other unique `ID` will have its own group.

Aggregate functions take care of the other fields, including logic to take the `min()` value for `Field A` which seems to fit your requirement

Comment: This works but I won't voted as the answer since It wasn't the first suggestion. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel Gordon was the last user to post an answer, Zaynul was first, though, that is not technically how this process works.  You should select the best (most helpful) post as your accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

you can try by using case when

```
select case when id in(1,3) then 'A' else 'B' end as field,sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from tablename group by case when id in(1,3) then 'A' else 'B' end
```

Comment: This works but I won't voted as the answer since It wasn't the first suggestion. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

I think simple aggregation does what you want:

```
select min(id) as id, min(fieldA) as fieldA, sum(quantity) as quantity
from t
group by (case when id in (1, 3) then 1 else id end);
```